# FAIL Filling range of graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

As title I use matplotlib `plt.fill_between` to filling range.

The green line is my averaged data
[image]

I choose 25% data and 75% data before averaging to my lower_bound and upper_bound

```
plt.plot(ave_data, color = 'green', alpha = 0.5)
upper_bound = ave_data + np.array(upper)
lower_bound = ave_data - np.array(lower)
plt.fill_between(ave_data, upper_bound, lower_bound, facecolor='lightblue')
plt.show()
```

and I expected picture should like:
[image]

but I got this:

[image]

Where am i doing wrong??

Comment: You should pass an x value to plot/fill_betwen both times.

Answer (score 1):

The [first parameter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html) of `fill_between` is the *x*-axis, not `ave_data`. You can simple change your code `x = range(0, len(ave_data))` to:

```
x = range(0, len(ave_data))
plt.plot(ave_data, color='blue', label='Rural', linewidth=0.1)
plt.fill_between(x, upper_bound, lower_bound, facecolor = 'lightblue', alpha =.25)
```

Result:
[image]